# Opening a file in Python given the dirrectory

Tags: python, file-io

If I have the following directory to a file, how would I go about opening that file and then reading the contents from that file?. I know how to open the file if it is just the one file, when I open the file nothing happens.

I have the following code:

what I want to do is open the file found that matches, and then look through that file looking for a specific row (based on other variables) and then return one item of Data (aka, one field in one row)

```
   data_paths = [] 
   data_paths.append(r'\\..\..\..\..\..\....\AV_only') 
   data_paths.append(r'\\..\..\...\..\..\..\all') 

 configfiles = []
for path in data_paths:
    configfiles.append(glob.glob(path+"/" + server +"*"))




heading = True
for fileListing in configfiles:
    for root, dirs, fnames in os.walk(fileListing): 
        for fname in fnames:
            print fileListing        # items is a list here
            print "Success:"


            print "Item 0" + fileListing[0]

            for elements in fileListing:
                f = file(elements,"r")
                reader = f.read()
                rownum = 0
                for row in reader:
                # Save header row.
                    if rownum == 0:
                        header = row
                    else:
                        colnum = 0
                        for col in row:
                            print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col)
                            colnum += 1

                rownum += 1

                f.close()
```

It is not printing anything, even though it should...

The file dirrectory that im pointing to will have apx 20 files in eg

```
server1.txt
server1.csv
serverx.txt
```

the file types will be a mixtures of .txt and .csv files: might it have something to do with that?

Edit: The configfiles look like the following:

```
Config Files[['\\\\...\\...\\...\\...\\...\\...\\...\\x\\server.csv'], ['\\\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\all\\server.txt']]
```

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? `r'\\..\..\..\..\..\....\AV_only'` contains four periods in a row, which doesn't look right. The `configfiles` list is probably empty, so it won't do anything.

Comment: I will edit the post now to give what the config files look like :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did something similar to this recently.  See if I can help you out.  I think you might want to try something like this:

```
for elements in fileListing:
    #add this just to ensure file location
    print os.path.abspath(elements)
    for line in open(elements, 'r'):  #this does a line by line read of the file
        print line
```